# List just your repos on Github repositories page

Tags: github

There is a search field on the GitHub repositories page, but I don’t know what text to enter that would filter out forks. Also the Type and Language dropdowns don’t have required filter.

How do you list just your repositories, excluding any forks, on the GitHub repositories page?

Answer (score 2):

Say, your GitHub username is `usertest`.
If you want to see non-forks, go to the following link (change `usertest` to your GitHub username):

```
https://github.com/usertest?tab=repositories&q=&type=source&language=
```

If you want to see non-forks with the C language, use the following link (change `usertest` to your GitHub username):

```
https://github.com/usertest?tab=repositories&q=&type=source&language=C
```

`private`, `public`, `archived` and `mirror` are valid, too.
If you want to see forks, change `source` to `fork`.

Hope this clears your doubts.